# Is there any way of testing antioxidant ability of different substances?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-oxidation

For my investigation, I am looking at the antioxidant levels of different types of tea. How could I compare the antioxidating ability of each tea?

For example, I know there is a method calling for DPPH radical and absolute ethanol, which I do not have at my disposal. Do you know any other method I could use?

Comment: Title and text do not strictly correspond. To the title the answer is reasonably yes in the sense while having reliable methods for mixtures and solutions might be, as it seems to a non specialist, complicated.

Comment: Could you please clarify your point?

Comment: The problem is that teas are not made of a single substance. For "food" the orax scale went common but I think its use is now deprecated.